# Is there a way to automate authentication on Google Drive?

Tags: php, authentication, google-drive-api

I wrote a PHP application to upload a text file, then encrypts the file and stores it on our server. I need to use Google Drive API to upload these encrypted files by pressing one button, which is the upload button in my application without the user going thru the authentication process. Is it possible to automate the authentication process all in the backend with PHP in my application? If so what how do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by automating the authentication process?

Comment: Authentication done completely in backend without user intervention.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to leave out the auth. But you may prefer to use the Save to Drive button, which basically handles the auth by itself: https://developers.google.com/drive/savetodrive

Comment: Thank you for this. But this does not allow me to upload a file on someone else's g-drive. I need to be able to have a user upload an encrypted file on someone else's google drive for this application.

Comment: Then you need to go through the authorization and authentication process, otherwise how can we let you upload a file to someone's Drive?

Comment: I understand. What I am asking is to how do the authentication by the back end code versus the user, using Client ID and Client Secret, so the user can upload a file to someone else's drive. Now that I think about Google probably does not allow this due to security reasons. But then using the Client ID and Client Secret can be somewhat secure? I guess its a double edge sword Google wanted to avoid.

Comment: Why don't you upload files to a service account's Drive?

Comment: We decided to use a server in the company to upload files to.